# jQuery .toggle() equivalent in Google Closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am rewriting some of my javascript files to get rid of the jQuery and use Google Closure instead. I have got a date picker which a user can toggle to show or to hide. At the moment the following code is being used:

```
if (this.open == open)
    return false;

$(this.elDatePicker).toggle(open);
this.open = open;
return true;
```

Where el.DatePicker is the element with the date picker inside, in this case a div.

I am looking for a way to rewrite this piece of code to change the jQuery to Google Closure. Any idea's how this should be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
goog.style.showElement(this.elDatePicker, !goog.style.isElementShown(this.elDatePicker));
```

Source:
[Google Closure Style.js Doc](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_style_style.js.html)

Answer (score 1):

For reference

With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:

Source : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

if so then setting either `display` none or `visibility` : hidden/visible. should be sufficient.

you can use [goog.style.setStyle(element, style, opt_value)](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_style_style.js.html)

here is a jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/ENOX/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle a specific CSS clas, you can use:

```
goog.dom.classlist.toggle(element, 'className');
```

Comment: This doesnt correctly answer the question, it is not the same as the jQuery.toggle()

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zippy class without a header element,

```
this.zippy = new goog.ui.AnimatedZippy(null, this.elDatePicker);
```

(...)

```
this.zippy.setExpanded(open)
```